# setting a CSS role with :host ::ng-deep into an angular component CSS is not working?

Tags: css, angular, sass, web-frontend

Trying to set a CSS prop of an angular component by using

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-panel {
  transform-origin: center bottom !important;
  top: -119px !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

is not working but when I remove the :host and ::ng-deep from the above code it works just fine
but the problem is doing that means this CSS rules starts leaking into other components as well. I went through the docs again and wasn't able to find the reason as to why this might happen.

Answer (score 0):

This should isolate the styles to the parent-element-className css class:

```
.parent-element-className {
  ::ng-deep .p-dropdown-panel {
    transform-origin: center bottom !important;
    top: -119px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Customizing Angular Material Classes with ::ng-deep

---

#### Keywords

`Angular Material` `::ng-deep` `CSS` `View Encapsulation` `Deprecated`

---

### Introduction to ::ng-deep

Angular Material provides a set of UI components that are widely used in Angular applications. To customize these components, developers may need to override the default styles.

- **Use of ::ng-deep**: The `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selector allows developers to apply styles to child components without the limitations of Angular's view encapsulation.
- **Deprecated Feature**: Despite its usefulness, `::ng-deep` is deprecated and should be used cautiously. Angular recommends alternative methods for styling.

---

### Example of Using ::ng-deep

Here's how to apply custom styles to Angular Material components using `::ng-deep`:

- **Customizing Buttons**:

  - Target: `.mat-button`
  - Custom Style: Background color set to a green shade (`#4CAF50`) and text color to white.
- **Customizing Cards**:

  - Target: `.mat-card`
  - Custom Style: Box shadow with a light grey color (`#888888`).

#### Figures

**Custom Style Application:**

```
graph TB;
    A["::ng-deep Selector"] --> B["Angular Material Components"]
    B --> C[".mat-button"]
    B --> D[".mat-card"]
    C --> E["Custom Background & Text Color"]
    D --> F["Custom Box Shadow"]
```

#### Images

### Alternatives to ::ng-deep

- **Component-Specific Styles**: Define styles within the component's CSS file without using `::ng-deep`.
- **View Encapsulation**: Utilize Angular's View Encapsulation feature to control how styles are applied to components.

Remember, while `::ng-deep` can be a quick fix, it's important to plan for its removal by adopting recommended styling practices.

#### Sources

- Angular Material Documentation
- Angular Guide on Component Styles

Comment: Well, View Encapsulation is created for using Shadow Dom. On the contrary ng deep is the syntax to allow override styles. DEPRECRATED is wrong.